# Index.js.erb file not working in rails 5.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I am following a tutorial from devfactor.com. It's called "Let's Build: Instagram with Rails." The author is using AJAX and js files in the tutorial. When added a file called "Index.js.erb", it showed many errors in my server. 
Error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial posts/_posts, application/_posts wi
th {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :er
b, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/Users/alouftur0/Rails/Photogram/app/views"
  * "C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/kaminari-core-1.0.1/app/views"
  * "C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/app/views"
):
    1: $('#posts').append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'posts')%>");
    2: $('#paginator').html("<%= escape_javascript(link_to_next_page(@posts, 'LO
AD MORE', remote: true, id: 'load_more'))%>");
    3: if (!$('#load_more').length) { $('#paginator').remove(); }

app/views/posts/index.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_posts_index_js_erb___1182481000_10
4067220'
```

Here are the files:

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Photogram</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
  <%= render 'posts/navbar' %>
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
  <% end %>
  <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Index.html.erb:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= render 'post', post: post %>
<% end %>
<div class="text-center" id="paginator">
  <%= link_to_next_page @posts, 'LOAD MORE', remote: true, id: 'load_more' %>
</div>
```

index.js.erb:

```
$('#posts').append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'posts')%>");
$('#paginator').html("<%= escape_javascript(link_to_next_page(@posts, 'LOAD MORE', remote: true, id: 'load_more'))%>");
if (!$('#load_more').length) { $('#paginator').remove(); }
```

application.scss:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
 @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
 @import "bootstrap";
```

application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, or any plugin's
// vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file. JavaScript code in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require rails-ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree
```

That's it. The error message is above. if you have any questions, just comment it. Thank you!
 Here is my Posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    before_action :owned_post, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
    def index
      @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC').page params[:page]
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html
      end
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
      @post = current_user.posts.build
    end

    def create
      @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
      if @post.save
        redirect_to posts_path
        flash[:success] = "Post Created!"
      else
        flash.now[:success] = "Your new post couldn't be created!  Please check the form."
        render :new
      end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
      if @post.update(post_params)
        redirect_to posts_path
      else
        flash.now[:alert] = "Update failed.  Please check the form."
        render :edit
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @post.destroy
      redirect_to root_path
      flash[:success] = "Destroyed ;)"
    end

    private

    def owned_post
      unless current_user == @post.user
        flash[:success]= "That post doesn't belong to you :("
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    end

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:image, :caption)
    end

    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
```

Comment: Add your controller to the question.

Comment: here, I added it!

Comment: Do you have your views/posts/_posts partial?

Comment: yes, should l include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to render partial such as

```
$('#posts').append('<%= escape_javascript(render @posts) %>');
```

Comment: l did it, but the action l wanted it to do didn't work?

Comment: You need to use single quotes also. I edited my answer

Comment: still, nothing happened when l clicked the button?

Comment: should l restart my server?

Comment: it renders the file but does nothing. Why?

Comment: do you have element with id 'posts'?

Comment: You need to create it, your partial will be inserted to it

Comment: l will try that!

Comment: Have any results?

Answer (score 0):

Your `index.html.erb` file is missing a `#posts` selector for the `$('#posts').append('<%= escape_javascript(render @posts) %>')` command in `index.js.erb` to append to.

```
<div id="posts">
  <%= render 'posts' %>
</div>
<div class="text-center" id="paginator">
  <%= link_to_next_page @posts, 'LOAD MORE', remote: true, id: 'load_more' %>
</div>
```

As the error suggests, you also need a `posts/_post.html.erb` partial, which is what the JS partial is trying to render.

Comment: Can you write out what l need to write in my files please

Comment: Also, the error stopped happening, the button doesn't do anything. Why?

Comment: Ok, I added an example.